# Function to Call Async Sub finishing Function Before Async

Tags: vb.net, async-await, httpclient

Using HttpClient sub in a DLL.  But the calling app wants to get a True or False as a return that the HttpClient worked.

So I tried to write a simple calling app like so

```
 Public Function SendBasket() As Integer
    Try
        SendMarketBasket()

        If MktResp = "Loaded" Then
            Return 0
        ElseIf MktResp = "Nothing to Load" Then
            Return -1
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return -1
    End Try
End Function

Private Async Sub SendMarketBasket()........
```

Obviously the If statement after the call to the Async call runs immediately before the MktResp is set.  How can I return the function result only after the Async call completes?

TIA
Harry

Comment: I don't think there is any way to tell when an `Async Sub` completes - they are fire-and-forget.  You could change it to `Private Async Function SendMarketBasket() As Task` and use `SendMarketBasket().Wait()` but that may deadlock.  [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343594/how-to-call-asynchronous-method-from-synchronous-method-in-c) has some good info, and there are probably others.

Answer (score 3):

Change your `SendMarketBasket` method to return `Task`.
Then you can "await" for task get completed and continue execution your code based on the returned result

```
Private Async Function SendMarketBasketAsync() As Task
    ' your code
End Function
```

Then you need change signature of `SendBasket` method to asynchronous too.

```
Public Async Function SendBasketAsync() As Task(Of Integer)
    Await SendMarketBasketAsync()

    If MktResp = "Loaded" Then
        Return 0
    ElseIf MktResp = "Nothing to Load" Then
        Return -1
    End If
End Function
```

If you add `Async` suffix to the asynchronous methods it will save your and your colleagues time.

`Async` is like zombie if you start using it somewhere it will spread over all of your application - this is not a bad thing :)